# Change List of string to List of Dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a some funny data:

```py
<class 'list'>
["[{'address': 'sample', 'address2': 'sample2'}]"]
```

it is a `list` of `string` and I would like to have a something like this

```py
<class 'list'>
[{'address': 'sample', 'address2': 'sample2'}]
```

-> `List` of `Dict`. How could I achieve it please? Btw. I have no idea how many `pairs` will be in `dict` but there will be only one `dict` inside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this works for me:

```
>>> import json
>>> a = ["[{'address': 'sample', 'address2': 'sample2'}]"]
>>> b = [ json.loads(i.replace("'",'"')) for i in a]
>>> b
[[{'address2': 'sample2', 'address': 'sample'}]]
>>>
```

If you're sure there's only one `dict` inside, things become simpler:

```
>>> json.loads(a[0].replace("'",'"'))
[{'address': 'sample', 'address2': 'sample2'}]
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Best would be fixing the serializer in the first place.

If that's not an option, perhaps you could try using a YAML parser

```
>>> import yaml
>>> L = ["[{'address': 'sample', 'address2': 'sample2'}]"]
>>> yaml.safe_load(L[0])
[{'address': 'sample', 'address2': 'sample2'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

`yaml` works fine but you can use `ast.literal_eval` (built-in) so that you don't have to install new libs:

```
import ast
x = ast.literal_eval("[{'address': 'sample', 'address2': 'sample2'}]")
print(x)
print(type(x))
#[{'address': 'sample', 'address2': 'sample2'}]
#<class 'list'>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can determine the format of the data, maybe you can simply treat it as `json` string.

```py
import json

data = ["[{'address': 'sample', 'address2': 'sample2'}]"]
print([json.loads(item.replace("'", '"')) for item in data])


output:
[[{'address': 'sample', 'address2': 'sample2'}]]
```